# How can I set a policy for an s3 bucket that allows authenticated users to list the bucket or get any file from the bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have set a *permission* on the bucket that allows "Authenticated Users" to list, upload, and delete from a bucket I created. This seems to allow me to upload files to the bucket, but it appears that downloading files from the bucket is not covered by this permission, and I instead need to define a *policy* for the bucket. It's not clear to me how to set such a policy. I tried the policy generator with my best guesses at what I should fill in, but the result was not a valid policy when I pasted it in as a new policy for the bucket (it failed with the message `Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement - Action "s3:ListBucket" in Statement "Stmt-some-number"`). Can someone explain what is wrong with the following policy and how to set it correctly to allow authenticated users to retrieve files from the bucket?

```
{
  "Id": "Policy-some-number",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt-some-number",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 93):

`s3:GetObject` applies to the objects in the bucket so the Resource is correct: `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"`.

`s3:ListBucket` applies to the Bucket itself and so the Resource should be `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"`

your resulting policy should resemble:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy-some-number",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt-some-number",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt-some-other-number",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: does that mean that you have to use separate "Statement" for "s3:GetObject" and "s3:ListBucket" ?

Comment: @Tjunkie yes, because the `Resource` is different.

Comment: The fact is incorrect, Resource can be "merge"  , just use [ ] join both as a list.

Comment: @c4urself +1 and thank you for explaining this. I'm incredulous that after an hour+ and reading several AWS docs that this wasn't clear. Even the policy generator got this wrong.

Comment: I second @SaxDaddy - Amazon's own policy generator was just flat wrong

Comment: Missed the /* too which caused "Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy;" in my case. Solved by having 2 Statements with and without /*

Answer (score 42):

Just to compliment @c4urself answer. the answer help solve my issue as well, but there is some indication from AWS documentation, which you can add more than one resource, just use [] to make them a list.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html#vpc-endpoints-s3-bucket-policies

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Access-to-specific-bucket-only",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update Bucket policy as below

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1546023103427",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1546023101836",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::usagereports-atul",
            "arn:aws:s3:::usagereports-atul/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: How does this answer differ from the others that have been posted over the past 4 years? You provide no explanation, and the provided configuration does not seem related to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the resource and array/list of resources and add an item to the list with /* as s3:GetObject applies to arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket/*. See below

```
 "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::my_secure_bucket/*"
```