# Amazon S3 IAM User can' access S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My users get the message

> You don't have permissions to use the Amazon S3 Console

I don't understand why. The users belong to a group that has this policy I made with the help of the `Policy Generator`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449507915000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the `Policy Generator` I selected the following:

> Effect: Allow
>
> AWS Service: Amazon S3
>
> Amazon Resource Name (ARN): "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis"

The bucket name is `fouraxis`

Clearly, I'm missing something.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600137/how-can-i-set-a-policy-for-an-s3-bucket-that-allows-authenticated-users-to-list/28489312#28489312

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S3 console uses the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` API method to drive the UI.  You would need to add this permission for users to log into the console and browse S3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1449507915000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::fouraxis"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListAllBuckets",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This worked, but this shows all admin's buckets in IAM console. What if admin want to show only one bucket (in case of this thread, fouraxis) for which permission is granted?

Comment: I don't believe the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` action can be controlled at the individual bucket level, it always enumerates all the buckets in the account.  You can control access to read the contents of the bucket through ListBucket and GetObject permissions.