# I can't acces an object on Amazon S3 in a bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I was trying the whole afternoon to access an object on a bucket on Amazon S3. I'm only allowed to access this object and not the whole bucket.

P.S : I'm not the admin of the S3 bucket and the allowed to only access an object.

Uri looks like this : s3://my-bucket/project

I have the access and secret key and it works fine when I'm using Cloudberry, I can access the object "project" and all the files in the path "my-bucket/project".

But I'm trying to access this object using Python and apprently it's not working at all. I get an access denial error. Here is the code I try :

```
import boto3
ACCESS_KEY = "**********"
SECRET_KEY = "**********"


s3 = boto3.client(
"s3",
aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
)
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'

response = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix='/project')
```

Here is the error I get :

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: Please share your IAM permissions.

Comment: If you only have access to a single key, you won't be able to do `ListObjects` on the bucket.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but you will eventually also need to remove the leading `/` from `/project`.  The leading `/` isn"t part of the object key.

Comment: I really wonder what do you guys mean with "Key" ?  - Also, dear Michael, I tried it without / and it didn't work. Is it having the access and secret key not enough to access an object using boto3 ? I mean why would I have access to the object using Cloudberry or Cyberduck but when using the S3 API, it's returning a denial access error ? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a policy for an s3 bucket that allows authenticated users to list the bucket or get any file from the bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600137/how-can-i-set-a-policy-for-an-s3-bucket-that-allows-authenticated-users-to-list)

Comment: dear @mootmoot , I'm not the admin of the bucket :) !

Comment: When you say `Cloudberry`, do you mean the backup services or the interface client ?   By the way, you can setup aws  cli in your machine with the credential, if the awscli `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/project` doesn't works, that's mean bucket policies is restricted.  A bucket policy can restrict connection from particular address, IAM roles, etc.

Comment: Triple-check the credentials you are supplying to boto3. If they are 100% correct and the same as you are using with CyberDuck then talk to your admin to help debug the IAM/S3 policies. Also, a few things you should change: 1) use list_objects_v2, not list_objects 2) indicate a prefix of project/ rather than /project if project is a folder 3) don't hard-code credentials in your script (use credentials file or environment variables instead).